# flutter draw arc layout

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Could anyone lead me in the right direction to build something like the following image

[image]

Comment: see https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_svg

Comment: @pskink 
if i use SVG  how i make menu button clickable ??

Comment: you have to use `FlatButton` for example

Comment: @pskink and position for button

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html

Comment: @pskink please you have example like it , i try but i cannot, thanks

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: i convert curves to svg  and try to put buttons but its look same in different screen size

Comment: so you have to scale them

Comment: @pskink no the position for buttons changed when screen size changing

Comment: you have to scale `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` properties of `Positioned` widget

Comment: @pskink sorry i don-not understand your point

Comment: try this: https://pastebin.com/raw/Kp977BJ5 - call `buildStack` method to initialize the `body` property of your main `Scaffold` (or wherever you like)

Comment: @pskink i still checking

Comment: you still checking what?

Comment: @pskink i try to make design fit screen width and height but not fit  button disappear

Comment: i have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @pskink with his help

```
class ButtonData {
  String text;
  Rect rect;
  double leftRadius;
  double rightRadius;

  ButtonData(this.text, this.rect, this.leftRadius, this.rightRadius);
}

Widget buildStack() {
  return LayoutBuilder(builder: (ctx, constraints) {
    var fs = applyBoxFit(BoxFit.contain, Size(32.0, 32.0), constraints.biggest);
    double scale = fs.destination.width / fs.source.width;
    print("sclae $scale");
    List<Widget> children = [
      SvgPicture.asset(
        "assets/drawing.svg",
        width: fs.destination.width,
        height: fs.destination.height,
      )
    ];
    var buttons = [
      ButtonData("button 1", Rect.fromLTWH(9.75, 4.75, 14.5, 4.5), 0, 1),
      ButtonData("button 2", Rect.fromLTWH(7.25, 10.75, 14.5, 4.5), 1, 0),
      ButtonData("button 3", Rect.fromLTWH(9.75, 16.75, 14.5, 4.5), 0, 1),
      ButtonData("button 4", Rect.fromLTWH(7.25, 22.75, 14.5, 4.5), 1, 0),
    ];
    children += buttons.map((buttonData) {
      return Positioned(
        left: buttonData.rect.left * scale,
        top: buttonData.rect.top * scale,
        width: buttonData.rect.width * scale,
        height: buttonData.rect.height * scale,
        child: OutlineButton(
          highlightColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
              left: Radius.circular(4.5 * scale * buttonData.leftRadius),
              right: Radius.circular(4.5 * scale * buttonData.rightRadius),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print("onPressed ${buttonData.text}");
          },
          child: Text(
            buttonData.text,
            textScaleFactor: 0.225 * scale,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();

    return Stack(children: children);
  });
}

/*
assets/drawing.svg:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="32"
   height="32"
   id="svg3352"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r"
   viewBox="0 0 32 32"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs3354" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="16.75"
     inkscape:cx="16"
     inkscape:cy="16"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="true"
     inkscape:grid-bbox="true"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     objecttolerance="10000"
     guidetolerance="10000"
     showguides="true"
     inkscape:guide-bbox="true"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="717"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="25"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid3360" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <metadata
     id="metadata3357">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1"
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer">
    <path
       id="path4184"
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000075;stroke-width:1.0;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 6,4 5,0 0,0 11,0.034947 c 1.637555,2e-7 2.965056,1.3275011 2.965056,2.9650564 0,1.6375553 -1.327501,2.9650563 -2.965056,2.9650565 L 9.4650564,10.034947 c -1.6375557,0 -2.9650567,1.327501 -2.9650564,2.965057 2e-7,1.637555 1.3275011,2.965056 2.9650563,2.965056 L 22,16.034947 c 1.637556,0 2.965056,1.327501 2.965056,2.965057 0,1.637555 -1.327501,2.965056 -2.965056,2.965056 L 9.4650564,22.03495 c -1.6375557,0 -2.9650567,1.327501 -2.9650564,2.965057 2e-7,1.637555 1.3275011,2.965056 2.9650563,2.965056 L 20,28 l 5,0 0,0"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccsccsccsccscccc" />
  </g>
</svg>

 */
```